# PySpark get checkpoint directory (version < 3.1.0)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-zeppelin

We can set the checkpoint directory path in PySpark using the code below:

```py
spark.sparkContext.setCheckpointDir('/checkpoints')
```

As [`SparkContext.getCheckpointDir()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.SparkContext.getCheckpointDir.html) is only introduced in PySpark version 3.1.0, how to get the checkpoint directory path using an older version PySpark like v2.4.3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`SparkContext.getCheckpointDir()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.SparkContext.getCheckpointDir.html) is only implemented in PySpark version 3.1.0, but luckily it was already implemented in the underlying Scala codebase in `v2.4.3`. You can see that [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/c3e32bf06c35ba2580d46150923abfa795b4446a/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.scala#L2355).

You can access the underlying sparksession (JavaSparkContext) with the `_jsc` attribute. The following works in a pyspark REPL on version `2.4.5`:

```py
>>> spark.sparkContext.setCheckpointDir('/checkpoints')
>>> sc._jsc.sc().getCheckpointDir().get()
'file:/checkpoints/1829fbb4-0b7b-44c5-b275-50276d063565'
```