# Pyspark clean Checkpoints using spark.cleaner.referenceTracking.cleanCheckpoints

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have found out Spark has a [clean checkpoint functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#:%7E:text=spark.cleaner.referenceTracking.cleanCheckpoints) that allow us to delete checkpoint that are out of scope. I found out the code is written in [scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ContextCleaner.scala).

1. How to call this function (**spark.cleaner.referenceTracking.cleanCheckpoints**) using Pyspark?
2. Can we call the function using the same [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76071692/pyspark-get-checkpoint-directory-version-3-1-0) here?

**Sample Code:** on configuration for checkpointLocation
The checkpoint will be stored in local file system, although documentation recommend storing in HDFS.

```
    df.writeStream \
        .foreachBatch(data_preprocessing) \
        .option("checkpointLocation", jsonConfig_main["Spark"]["checkpoint"]) \
        .start() \
        .awaitTermination()
```